# No sketches show up when trying to link more of them

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

I want to put all my sketches on a website and display them when a button is pressed. For testing purposes I have simply put a `no-display` class which hides the preview. When removing the tag, the canvas doesn't show up.

[Here is my website](http://tudor0404.github.io) , and [this is the source code](https://github.com/Tudor0404/tudor0404.github.io).

I have only put this function on some sketches (put the sketch in the parent div and resize the canvas), to make sure it works. The website is bare bones right now so I haven't added the functionality to hide and show those sketches.

My problem is, that the sketch(s) don't show up, even when I remove the tag. And I want to know if there is anyway to reduce how active those sketches are when not being shown, so the website doesn't become laggy.

The black tint is the background of the full screen preview. Also, When using only one script, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your sketches are using **global mode** which means you're defining global functions like this:

```
function setup(){
  // code
}

function draw(){
  //code
}
```

You're doing this in each sketch file, so you have a bunch of functions with the same name. I'm pretty sure this means that last sketch loaded will overwrite all of the others, but in any case this definitely won't work how you're expecting it to.

Instead, you need to use **instance mode** so that each sketch is self-contained. You can read more about instance mode [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode), but here's a basic example:

```
var s = function( sketch ) {

  var x = 100; 
  var y = 100;

  sketch.setup = function() {
    sketch.createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  sketch.draw = function() {
    sketch.background(0);
    sketch.fill(255);
    sketch.rect(x,y,50,50);
  };
};

var myp5 = new p5(s);
```

You would do something similar for each of your sketches, so that they're self-contained and don't overwrite each other's global functions.

I also recommend that you try to [work in smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program). Get this working with two simple sketches before you try expanding this to your whole portfolio.

Comment: Could I switch between each file maybe? So I don't have to change all the code and maybe reduce the load of running all the script? Also thanks for the detailed answer. I don't think this will be a permanent portfolio, just temporary until I learn more of JavaScript and CSS.